# Error calculating diffusion equation solution by fft

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab, octave

I''m trying to compute the solutions of:
$$\partial_tu=\partial_{xx}u$$ with $x\in[0,1]$ and initial conditions$$u(0,x)=sin(\pi x) $$
Solution are periodic. We have to apply forward euler in time and fft in space and compute the solution in $t=1$.

I've made this code in octave/matlab to do so, but can't obtain the correct result. Anyone has any hint or spots the error?

thank you.

```
%number of nodes, space step, nodes, time step
N=50;
h=1/N;
x=h*(1:N); 
t=0; 
dt=h/1000;

%initial condition
u_0=sin(pi.*x); 
%auxiliar variable for the while part
u_aux=u_0; 

while (t<=1)
%apply transform
u_n=fft(u_aux);
%perform second derivative
u_n_2_derivative=(1i*1i*[0:N/2-1 0 -N/2+1:-1].*[0:N/2-1 0 -N/2+1:-1]).*u_n;
%inverse transform
u_n_xx=real(ifft(u_n_2_derivative));
%do the time step
u_nn=u_aux+dt.*u_n_xx;
%renew variables
u_aux=u_nn;
t=t+dt;
endwhile

plot(x,sol)
```

Comment: First of all the solution should be something like $u(x,t) = e^{-\pi^2 t}\sin(\pi x)$ and secondly you should not have to need to perform any explicit time-stepping here since using fourier transforms we have $u(x,t) = \mathcal{F}^{-1}[\mathcal{F}[u_0(x)]e^{-k^2 t}]$.